# yii2: using a getter from a view

Tags: yii2, getter

**I have a user_detail table**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_detail` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
);
```

I want to retrieve the value of `user_detail`.`name` in main.php to display the loggedin user's name.

**in UserDelail class I added a getter:**

```
public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserDetail::className(), ['userID' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    }
```

**In main.php I have** `<?= UserDetail::getFullName()->name ?>`

and I am getting:
*Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::hasOne()*

What is wrong here? and how can i correct that?

Thank you

Comment: Which class *UserDelail* extends ?

Comment: it extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord

and it is linked to User with a FK (userID)

Answer (score 1):

edit.

To get current logged user data u can simply:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->id
Yii::$app->user->identity->name
```

And u can do it wherever: directly in the view, in controller, model and so on...

---

Why u are making realtion to ClassX in ClassX.

The whole idea of realtions is to connect ClassX to ClassY.

You should add in for example model/Project:

```
 public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'userId']);
    }
```

And the and in the model/User:

```
public function getProject() {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::className(), ['userId' => 'id' ] );
    }
```

Now when u want to throw out somedata from User table in Project/index for example you just (in model/project):

```
public function getUserName() {
        return $this->user ? $this->user->username : '- no user type-';
    }
```

Next in the project view/projectIndex:

```
'<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,        
 'filterModel' => $searchModel,       
        'columns' => [
'userName',
],]);
```

Or:

```
   <?php $new = new Project; ?>
   <?= $new->getUserName(); ?>
```

It all depends where and what for, you want to throw data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However I cannot do Yii::$app->user->identity->name because the details of the user is not found in User.  the details are in user_detail.

Comment: so just create function getUserName in your model and exract it from your user_detail by id.

Comment: @Michel, you want some clear example or now you know to do it?

Comment: I appreciate all help
Indeed this is what I did; I created a model for user_detail (UserDetail) where the name is stored and I created a getter (getFullName)[see details in my first post]. but it is not working, there is something missing that I cannot get my hands on

so please any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You haven't address the namepsace correctly in either your `View` file or your `Model class`

Please add something like `use app\models\UserDetail` at the top of your view file.

Comment: I have a use mentioned:
use backend\modules\hr\models\UserDetail;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it in the following way:

```
   public function getFullName()
    {
        $userInfo = UserDetail::findOne(['userID' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
        return $userInfo->first . ' ' . substr($userInfo->middle, 0,1) . '. ' . $userInfo->last;
    }
```

I do not like this solution but it is what I have for now in wait for a better solution.